# Using JSP or Spring tags in CSS files

Tags: css, spring, jsp

I'm working on a Spring MVC 3.2.4.FINAL application, and using JSP files as my view technology.  Part of my design uses imgs/etc in my css stylehsheet.

Ex:

```
.main #footer #footerlist {
    background: url( /resources/images/main-foot_impersonating.jpg ) no-repeat !important;
}
```

The problem, of course, is that the context path is not exposed.  I need to code this as:

```
.main #footer #footerlist {
    background: url( /contextRoot/resources/images/main-foot_impersonating.jpg ) no-repeat !important;
}
```

however, in an ideal world, I don't want to hard code the context root, and have Spring generate it automatically for me.  In a normal JSP file, I would be able to write it as:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/images/main-foot_impersonating.jpg" />
```

I realize, of course, that I can rename my css as a .css.jsp to force the JSP engine to compile it, and then code it as a jsp page, but I was wondering if there was another technique/solution.

I presume I must not be the first person who has needed to include some application values in a CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a hard and fast rule, but it's generally a best practice to make any urls in your css files relative instead of absolute. That way they never need to know where they are being deployed and "just work." For another stackoverflow discussion on the matter, see here: [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something like this on a project.

We made a spring controller mapped to the css or to the resources(the images) inside the css and the controller added the correct context.